# Is it possible to open SAP Analytics Cloud mobile app from a React Native app?

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, sap-analytics-cloud

I have developing a mobile app with React Native. I want to open SAP Analytics Cloud (SAC) app from my app.

I tried to open SAC app with "Linking" library but don't know how to find APP URL. How can I find SAC app URL or any specific app URL?
Thanks for your helps.

Answer (score 0):

The SAP Analytics Cloud iOS app offers a URL scheme for deep links, which when you open it from your app, will open the app:

`sap-analytics-cloud://<customerdomain>.<region>.<domain>/?type=story&id=<storyID>`

See the [help page](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ANALYTICS_CLOUD/00f68c2e08b941f081002fd3691d86a7/57a57b788a4447a3b7c6b43ec1be23c5.html?q=url#share-custom-url-scheme-links-(ios))